# Exporting the data in PDF or CSV is not working

Tags: jquery, csv, pdf

I am using datatable jquery , I am able to generate the sum on my page however  when  exporting the data in PDF or CSV SUM Count is not reflecting in exported page below is my script and table view, please suggest how to fix this

I am looking generate the sum counts in the same row where numbers are updated and should able to print or export this numbers
[image]

```js
$(function () {
     


       $('#mytable thead tr.filters th').each(function () {
           var title = $(this).text();


           if ($(this).hasClass("input-filter")) {


               $(this).html('<input name ="' + $.trim(title).replace(/ /g, '') + '" type="text" class = "form-control" placeholder="Search ' + $.trim(title) + '" />');
           }
           else if ($(this).hasClass("date-filter")) {

               $(this).html('<div class="input-prepend input-group"><span class="add-on input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" style="width: 200px" name="' + $.trim(title).replace(/ /g, '') + '"  placeholder="Search ' + $.trim(title) + '" class="form-control daterange"/></div>');

           }

       });

           

        // DataTable
        var table = $("#mytable").DataTable({
                     
            dom: "rBftlip",

            buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'collection',
                text: 'Export',
                buttons:
                    [
                               
                        {
                            extend: "copy",
                            exportOptions: { columns: ':visible:not(:last-child)' }, //last column has the action types detail/edit/delete
                            footer:true
                        },
                        {
                            extend: "csv",
                            exportOptions: { columns: ':visible:not(:last-child)' },
                            footer: true
                        },
                        {
                            extend: "excel",
                            exportOptions: { columns: ':visible:not(:last-child)' },
                            footer:true
                        },
                        {
                            extend: "pdf",
                            exportOptions: { columns: ':visible:not(:last-child)' },
                            footer:true
                        },
                        {
                            extend: "print",
                            exportOptions: { columns: ':visible:not(:last-child)' },
                            footer: true
                        }

                    ]
            }
            ],
           
            responsive: true,
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            orderCellsTop: true,
            scrollX: true,
            colReorder: true,
                    

            language: {
                search: '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>',
                searchPlaceholder: 'Search all columns',
                
                lengthMenu: '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></span>_MENU_</div>',
                processing: "<img src='../Content/images/ajax-loader.gif'>"
            },
                   
            processing: true,


            "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
                //  $("#mytable_processing").css("visibility", "hidden");
                $('#mytable').fadeIn();
            },
                

          
            "footerCallback": function( tfoot, data, start, end, display ) {
                var info = $('#mytable').DataTable().page.info();
                $(tfoot).find('td').eq(0).html("Total Count: " + info.recordsDisplay);

                     
            },
            
             "drawCallback": function () {
              var api = this.api();
              $("#sum").html(
                "Total Chargeback Amount: "+api.column( 4, {page:'current'} ).data().sum().toLocaleString('en-IN')
              );
            }
          
        });
```